# Jasper : Error with REST PHP Client

Tags: php, rest, client

I try to run a jasper report from a php script but it does not work.
This is what I am doing :

```
<?php
require_once "/opt/jrs-rest-php-client-2.0.0/vendor/autoload.php";

$c = new Client(
    "<my IP>",
    "8080",
    "<my login>",
    "<my password>",
    "jasperserver"
    );

$info = $c->serverInfo();
print_r($info);    

?>
```

This is the error message I have :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Jaspersoft\Exception\RESTRequestException: An
>   unexpected HTTP status code was returned by the server in
>   /opt/jrs-rest-php-client-2.0.0/src/Jaspersoft/Tool/RESTRequest.php:364
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /opt/jrs-rest-php-client-2.0.0/src/Jaspersoft/Tool/RESTRequest.php(451):
>   Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest->handleError(404, Array, 'prepAndSend('192.168.56.1/re...', Array,
>   'GET', NULL, true, 'application/jso...', 'application/jso...') #2
>   /opt/jrs-rest-php-client-2.0.0/tests2/test.php(43):
>   Jaspersoft\Client\Client->serverInfo() #3 {main} thrown in
>   /opt/jrs-rest-php-client-2.0.0/src/Jaspersoft/Tool/RESTRequest.php on
>   line 364

Any help or suggestion will be welcome.
Thanks

Comment: If it is [this client](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-php-client/blob/v2.0.0/src/Jaspersoft/Client/Client.php) you're using, then you need to do `new Client($serverUrl, $username, $password, $orgId)`. You're currently doing: `new Client($serverUrl, $serverPort, $username, $password, $orgId)`. Try to include the port number in the first argument instead, like this: `your_ip:8080`.

Comment: I have tried :
$c = new Client("http://localhost:8080/jasperserver","<my login>","<my password>", "");

and :
$c = new Client("http://localhost:8080/jasperserver","<my login>","<my password>");

but nothing works